# Bubble phenomenon

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, oscillators, bubbles

A few days ago I encountered a problem that caught my attention:

> The surface of an air bubble oscillates at a frequency of $20$ kHZ. We
> observe that this oscillation causes another air bubble nearby to
> oscillate. The oscillations are of very low amplitude compared with
> the other quantities.

How can we explain this phenomenon?

I am stuck on this interesting problem, I only have a hint as follows:  Establish the equation of motion of a water particle due to the "filling" of the retracted zone.  Then establish the equation for water pressure at a certain distance from the bubble, and linked it to the oscillation of the second bubble.

Comment: The surface oscillations of the first bubble cause waves to travel through the water between the bubbles. When the waves reach the other bubble, that causes the surface to oscillate.

Comment: Thank you, yes I understanded it intuitively, I  am looking for a way to prove it formally using physics principles.

Comment: It's hard to produce a formal answer to a conceptual question. Can you add details to your question about how exactly the bubble is vibrating? If you provide the source where you found the problem, that would also be useful.

Comment: Yes of course, it was an Ecole normal superieur entrance exam question, here is the source (in french) https://beos.prepas.org/sujet.php?id=6921.  I tried to translate as accurate as I can, In this context, the student is often asked to formulate reasonable hypotheses leading to a conceptual proof.

Answer (score 0):

The pulsating vibrations of one bubble induce an oscillating *flow field* in the surrounding fluid. That flow field then acts on the second bubble, causing its surface to move in synchrony with the first bubble.

The strength of the flow field diminishes with distance from the driving bubble, causing the amplitude of the sympathetic vibrations of the second bubble to become weaker.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understanded the phenomenon intuitively, but how to prove it formally, is it possible to reference me a modelisation that proves this fact ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem is spherically symmetrical, we can assume that the quantities depend only on $r$ and $t$. It's reasonable to assume that the liquid is incompressible, and to neglect the effect of gravity. And let $P_{0}$ the pressure in $+\infty$.

So, by conservation of flow, there is a constant that can only depend on $t$ such that $4\pi r^{2}v(r,t)=c(t)$ so $\vec{v(r,t)}=\frac{c(t)}{r^{2}} \vec{u_{r}}$.  Using the cinetic energy theorem, let $R(t)$ be the radius of the bubble at time $t$. We have $E_{c}=\frac{1}{2} \int_{R}^{+\infty} \frac{c^{2}}{r^{4}} \rho 4\pi r^{2} dr = \frac{2\pi \rho c^{2}}{R}$. Let's calculate the pressure forces acting on the fluid.

Let's consider a sphere of radius $r$ centered at $O$ the fluid beyond $r$ exerts a pressure $p(r,t)$ on this sphere the resulting power is calculated as $P(r)=-p(r,t) 4\pi c $. Similarly the bubble exerts a pressure $p(R,t)$ whose power is $P(R)=p(R,t) 4 \pi c$.

So the total power collected by all the fluid is : $$P_{T}=\lim_{r \to \infty} P(R)+P(r)=4 \pi c [p(R, t)- P_{0}]$$

And the cinetic energy theorem gives: $\frac{dE_{c}}{dt}=P_{T}$ since $c=R'R^{2}$ we find :  $$ p(R,t)=p_{0}+ \rho [R R'' + \frac{3}{2} R'^{2}]$$

Can we prove the claim from this ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It will be my pleasure to add more details about the calculations I made, to arrive to theses results, I just tried to skip the integral calculations parts.